# load image using picaso into hashmap and display using simpleadapter

Tags: listview, hashmap, simpleadapter

i want to load image using picaso into hashmap and display using simpleadapter in uicircular imageview. As this list is displaying text + circularImages. And data is comming in json format. I want to know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

To load the image in imageview you can use following line of code, which you will find in any website:

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```